# JQuery using percents or px depending on getting left or bottom position

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

When I try to have the left of an element with position absolute with jQuery, I get the result in px

`$("#element").css("left")` ---> 100px

When I try to do exactly the same with the bottom, I get a percentage

`$("#element").css("bottom")` ---> 20%

But I would need to get the px value on both cases. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: You can see the complete code here http://chiquiesteban.com/test.html

Comment: Just like the answers say below...however; you could apply simple math to get the pixel value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set styles on the `#element` of `left: 100px;` and `bottom: 20%;` ? I believe that the JQuery css() method will return what ever style has been set on the element.

Answer (score 1):

CSS function will return the CSS value you put. So if in your CSS you write `bottom : 20%;`, you'll get 20%.

Try checking [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) or [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) depending on what's your need.

Comment: Both (left and bottom) are set using percents, but only bottom is returning percents when asking for it via jQuery

Comment: Can you give me some direction where to check on the url you give us? I can't see where is the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The css returned will be in the format defined in the css.  If you use `$('#element').offset()` you will get back an object with the properties top and left, which will be in px, but will not have px in the unit returned (you would get back 100, not "100px", so you would have to tack that on to the end of it).  To get "bottom", you would need to do `parents_height - offet.top` (psuedo-code).